# Cumin in Taco Seasoning?

Tags: history

I've noticed that I never taste cumin in the tacos I get at restaurants, yet cumin is often the most noticeable flavor in pre-made taco seasonings. When and why did cumin get associated with tacos? Why is it not used in most restaurant preparations?

Comment: Because it's high in pottasium it can act as a preservative. And is used in chili powders. At restaurants where the food is made fresh there is no need to use pre made chilis powder or to use preservatives.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Do you think it originated with pre-made seasonings then? It would be nice if someone could track down a source on this. A possible complication: I've heard people associate this with tex-mex cooking, which on its face doesn't have anything to do with preservation.

Comment: A part of tex-mex is chili powder. And chili powder have cummin. And I would point to first commercialyl avaiable chili powder using cumin as a spice that is also preservative. Much better and tasteful than using celery.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY All chili powder doesn't contain cumin. The chili powder(s) we buy only consist of dried chilies.

Comment: @Cindy It's a strange thing. Because even McCormic list on their site "You might be surprised to know that chili powder is actually a blend of herbs and spices. Ours begins with whole, ripe chili peppers, toasted and mixed with ingredients including cumin, oregano, garlic and salt." But in the igredients list there is: CHILI PEPPER, SPICES, SALT, SILICON DIOXIDE (ADDED TO MAKE FREE FLOWING), AND GARLIC. So the cumin might be one of the "spices". But garlic and salt are listed and "cumin, oregano" are not.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY You are correct, and I do agree that McCormick and other mainstream brands use a blend as you describe. But, for many years now, we've bought a non-branded chili powder from a local grocery chain. Very plain packaging with only the name of the item and ingredient list on the cheap plastic package. The only ingredient listed was dried chili peppers, and you certainly can't taste anything else. Unfortunately the small chain went out of business last year. Hopefully we can find something the same or similar elsewhere.

Comment: @Cindy "chili powder" is a seasoning blend; it sounds like what you're buying is powdered chili pepper, which would be a single ingredient (much like garlic or onion powder); same or similar name, different product.

Comment: Cindy: I recommend going somewhere that carries actual Mexican brands; they'll have straight powder from several different chili pepper types (ancho, poblano, etc.)

Comment: @AllisonC As I said, that is not always the case. There are several questions on this site about chili powder. Many others have said the same as me. It can be a local/regional thing or a matter of terminology but, in some places, chili powder is just powdered chilies rather than a blend.

Comment: It's not a regional thing.  It's just American English being non-specific.  "chili powder" can refer either to powdered dried chiles (e.g. "cayenne chili powder") or the mix used for the American dish "chili".  Technically, the latter should be "chile powder", but frequently spice packagers don't distinguish.

Comment: the *former*, not the latter

Comment: I really recommend cumin in your guacamole, cheese sauce (macaroni & cheese, scalloped potatoes), and also tacos. Cumin is great.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm going to supplement Cindy's answer,  by addressing this part of the question:

> When and why did cumin get associated with tacos?

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tex-Mex), [Serious Eats](https://www.seriouseats.com/2014/05/draft-tex-mex-and-mexican.html), and [History.com](https://www.history.com/news/tracing-the-history-of-tex-mex), the cumin was brought by workers the Spanish imported to Texas from the Canary Islands in the 1500s, who themselves were the descendants of North Africans and hence had a love for cumin.  These workers introduced cumin into Tex-Mex cuisine, particularly Chile Con Carne, and when Willie Gebhardt created the first bottled "chili seasoning", it included cumin.  Many Americans encountered Gebhardt's seasoning a generation before they experienced any other kind of Mexican food, forever associating it with the cuisine.  And, for that matter, used Gebhardt's for taco meat, as my Oklahoma branch of the family did back into the 1930's.

The reason you don't encounter it in some Mexican restaurants it that the culinary staff are from Mexico, and not Texas or near Texas.  As such, they never "picked up" cumin.

(and yes, this does mean that Thrillist is wrong about the origin.  India was not involved)

Comment: A quibble: given that ~25% of food service workers are Hispanic or Latino, it's not unlikely that the staff at Tex-Mex restaurants actually is Mexican.  Anyway, it's the recipes, not the staff that count.

Comment: Right, I was including that: even in Tex-mex restaurants I know there's not much cumin unless you order the chili.  I believe there's also some swapping cumin in for cilantro since so many customers don't eat it, but I don't have any references for that.

Comment: This also raises the possibility that Chile Con Carne is as much a Spanish/African dish as it is a Mexican one.  Gonna have to research that.

Comment: @FuzzyChef have a look at tagine recipes like https://www.themediterraneandish.com/moroccan-vegetable-tagine-recipe/ and they'll look remarkably similar

Comment: um, not sure how that's similar to chile con carne?

Comment: Some places I have seen have a "gringo" taco made with a more Tex-Mex seasoning and lettuce/tomato/cheese.  It is quite interesting, as they still use less cumin usually than those pre-made powder concoctions :)

Answer (score 12):

As per your comment, the reason is Tex-mex flavor. Most of the pre-made 'Mexican' seasonings we get in the US have cumin and probably various other spices or flavorings not associated with authentic Mexican dishes.

If you look at recipes for authentic Mexican dishes, you won't typically find cumin in the ingredient list. While I like cumin in some Indian dishes or in chili, I find that I don't care for it in Mexican dishes. (And to be honest, I find it just as easy to add any desired spices as it would be to use a prepared package.)

You may find this article on [Thrillist](https://www.thrillist.com/eat/nation/what-is-tex-mex-food-difference-between-tex-mex-and-mexican) about the difference in Tex-Mex and Mexican food interesting. I'm sure an Internet search may yield many other articles.

Edited to add more info. From the linked article:

> The differences between Mexican and Tex-Mex food can be summed up in the use of a few key ingredients found in the US that are scarcely used anywhere South of the Rio Grande. These ingredients are: beef, yellow cheese (like cheddar), wheat flour, black beans, canned vegetables (especially tomatoes), and cumin.
>
> Chances are, if you're eating anything with one or more of those ingredients, it's Tex-Mex. Beef was the meat of choice for Texan ranchers back in the day, but it's hardly used in Mexican cuisine outside of the extreme Northern reaches of the country.
>
> Cumin was imported to the US and England from India, and, while it's been slowly incorporated into dishes in Mexico, the US was quicker to adopt it as a spice. And let's face it -- gringos love wheat, and pretty much any burrito you'll find up here is wrapped in a wheat tortilla rather than the maize-based tortillas down South. A general rule is that the more starch there is, the more Tex-Mex it is (with the notable exception of tortas).

Comment: This still raises the question (which SZCZERZO's comment goes some way toward answering): why cumin? Is it just that it goes well with chilies (as attested by Indian cuisine) and has certain desirable properties, or is there more to the story?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out something in addition to Cindy's answer which I do not see addressed, as I feel it adds much to the reason of why as well:  The predominant flavors of most authentic Mexican tacos are very simple, although delicious:  Protein, Cilantro, Onions, and Corn Tortilla (perhaps Lime, depends on where you are).  The blend of these flavors is very much a great combination, and needs little else, as the tortillas, cilantro, and onion all have a very pronounced flavor, even if the meat is more bland in nature.

Of course, from my understanding, things are a bit different depending on region as well, as tastes and common foods change as they would anywhere else.  In truth, there is a good bit of variance between TexMex, "Mexican", and truly authentic Mexican (both in restaurants and at home.)